# Subgradient of vector inside of square root of L2 norm?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following expression, I would like to take the sub-gradient of it with respect to $Z$.
Would someone help me with this?

$$\|Z\|^{0.5}_2$$

where $Z$ $\in\mathbb R^{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically by subgradient of a function $f$ one refers to *any* vector $v$ satisfying $f(y) \geq f(x) + v^T(y-x)$ $\forall y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ - the collection of these subgradients at a point $x$ is called the subdifferential and (I think) is what you are asking about.

Our particular $f(x) = \|x\|_2^{0.5}$ is non-convex and in fact has a subdifferential nowhere except for the origin, where the only subgradient is $\mathbf{0}$.

To gain intuition for this, take the 1-dimensional case $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$. Which tangent lines lie completely below the graph?
[image: Which tangent lines lie below the graph of \sqrt(x)?]

Comment: Thanks of your answer Eddie E !!!!